# Extracting data the ISE website using Matlab

Tags: matlab, finance

I'm trying to extract stock prices from the Irish Stock Exchange Website.  I'm getting errors for the lines using the function `datenum()`.

```
function get_ise_data(equity_name,equity,start_date,end_date)

% Example:
%   get_ise_data('CandC',22076,'01-Jan-2010','10-Jan-2010')
% Note:

% This program reads data from the ISE website. It creates a vector of
% trading days, and then requests data for each specific day from the
% website

% Specify the equity name and reference number, start and end dates as in
% the example above.

% C&C corresponds to the reference number 22076 and you can check this on ise.ie. Kerry 
% Group and BOI have similar reference numbers.
% The data is saved to a file called "[stock]data.mat". The first
% column is the date in serial number format. You can convert to string
% format using "datestr()" The graph produced is not automatically saved.
% The data is also saved to an excel file by the same name. When viewing in
% Excel we need to change the format of the first column to 'custom'
% and specify format as "hh:mm dd/mm/yy".
% Close the excel file before running the program.

% Convert start and end dates to serial format:
start_date = datenum(start_date, 'dd­-mmm­-yyyy');
end_date = datenum(end_date, 'dd­-mmm-­yyyy');

clear final_data

% Work out relevant trading days:

bdates = busdays(start_date, end_date, 'daily');

% The above assumes the same trading days as NYSE - need to modify this for the ISE. See the
% documentation of "busday" to change the default holidays.

itterations=length(bdates);
count=0;

% Loop over each trading day:

for i=1:itterations
    [year,month,date]=datevec(bdates(i));
    str1='http://www.ise.ie/Prices,-Indices-Stats/Equity­Market-Data/EquityDetails/?equity=';
    str2=sprintf('%d&start_day=%d&start_month=%d&start_year=%d',equity,date,month,year);
    url=sprintf('%s%s',str1,str2);
    raw=urlread(url); % Read in html code from website
    exp='<tr?\w+.*?>([\d]+:[\d]+)</\w+.*?>([%\­\d/:A-­Z\.]+)</\w+.*?>([%\­\d/:A­Z\.]+)</\w+.*?>([%\-\d/:A-Z\.]+)</\w+.*?>([%\-\d/:A­Z\.]+).*?/tr>';
    % The following extracts the parts of the html code that match the
    % format specified by 'exp':
    data = regexp(raw,exp,'tokens','freespacing');
    number_of_quotes=length(data);

    % Print out current day:
    sprintf('Now reading: date: %d, month: %d',date,month)
    % A number of quotes are given each day. Loop through these:

    for j=1:number_of_quotes
% Determine the serial date number of each quote:
time=data{1,j}(1,1);

hour=regexp(time{1,1},'([\d]+):[\d]+','tokens');
minute=regexp(time{1,1},'[\d]+:([\d]+)','tokens');
hour = str2double(cell2mat(hour{1,1}));
minute = str2double(cell2mat(minute{1,1}));
second=0;
time_serial _number=datenum(year,month,date,hour,minute,second);
price=str2double(cell2mat(data{1,j}(1,3)));
% Save the price and date number to temporary file, while ignoring
% missing data:
if ~isnan(price)
count=count+1;
final_data(count,1)=time_serial_number;
final_data(count,2)=price;
end
end % End of inter-­?day loop
end % End of daily loop
str=sprintf('% s_data',equity_name);
% Save data to hard disk:
save(str,'final_data');
xlswrite(str,final_data)
end
```

The error I get is

```
??? Error using ==> datenum at 182
DATENUM failed.

Error in ==> get_ise_data at 25
start_date = datenum(start_date, 'dd­-mmm-­yyyy');

Caused by:
    Error using ==> dtstr2dtnummx
    Failed on converting date string to date number.
```

Does anyone have any idea?  I think I've explained everything in the comments.

Ruth

Comment: At which line is the error? This line: `time_serial _number=datenum(year,month,date,hour,minute,second);` ? What is the error text? What are the values being input to datenum just before the error if you debug with a breakpoint for eg ? Please add that info to your question.

Comment: I've added the error message.  And what do you mean debug with a breakpoint?  I'm a bit of a matlab newbie.

Comment: oh ok - so I think your issue is that you've specified a `'ddmmmyyyy'` format but you giving it a `'dd-mmm-yyyy'` format string as an input. Change your inputs to look like `'01Jan2010'` rather than `'01-Jan-2010'`

Comment: A breakpoint is a way to tell your code to stop so that you can go through it step by step and check the states (values) of the variables at any step you like. To set a break point in matlab click on the little dashes on the left of your code, they should then turn to a red circle. You'll see some buttons on the top that allow you to step through your code line by line. This is very useful to find out where your code has gone wrong and why. Try find a tutorial , debugging is a vital programming skill!

Comment: Thanks for that but I actually have the hypens in my code.  They just hadn't copied over for some reason.

Comment: And I'll try a breakpoint!  Thanks!

Comment: @RuthO'Brien generally, you should boil down your code to as few lines as possible that demonstrate the problem.  95% of the the time I discover the bug myself during the process of simplifying my code into a proof of concept for the bug.

Comment: What are you passing to the `get_ise_data` function exactly? Are you calling it in a loop or something? It sounds to me like your problem is external to this function. Try call the function form the command line just using `get_ise_data('CandC',22076,'01-Jan-2010','10-Jan-2010')`, do you still get that same error?

Comment: Ya that's all I'm running! :(

Comment: @RuthO'Brien Are you sure? This specific error is triggered when the input string to `datenum` is not in the correct format. Can you print  `start_date` in MATLAB's command window and verify that it is in the correct result? Also verify its length.

Comment: It works if I just run `datenum('01-Jan-2010','dd-mmm-yyyy')` straight from the command window, but isn't working in my function.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that your date string does not conform to the format specified (hence the error message stating this) here:

```
start_date = datenum(start_date, 'dd­-mmm­-yyyy');
```

Check that the date strings being returned by the site are in the right format. In European countries it is common to return financial dates in the format: DD/MM/YY or DD/MM/YYYY

Set a break point at the line where the error is being reported and inspect the data being passed to datenum.